# MySQL error 1005 errno 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

I have created the following tables:

Stops:

```
CREATE TABLE Stop (  
 routeNo        DECIMAL (4,0) UNSIGNED,  
 stopNo         DECIMAL(3,0) UNSIGNED,  
 latitude       DECIMAL(19,16),  
 longitude      DECIMAL(19,16),  
 CONSTRAINT PK_Location PRIMARY KEY (routeNo, stopNo),  
 CONSTRAINT FK_stop_location FOREIGN KEY (latitude,longitude) REFERENCES Location(latitude,longitude),  
 CONSTRAINT FK_stop_route FOREIGN KEY (routeNo) REFERENCES Route(routeNo)  
);
```

And the table WorkDay:

```
CREATE TABLE Workday (
 theDate    DATE    PRIMARY KEY,
 notes  VARCHAR(30)
);
```

I then try to create the table Order Delivery with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDelivery 
(
 routeNo DECIMAL(4,0) UNSIGNED,
 stopNO DECIMAL(3,0) UNSIGNED, 
 orderNo INT(9),
 CONSTRAINT pk_Orders PRIMARY KEY (routeNo, stopNo, orderNo),
 deliveryDateExpected DATE, 
 deliveryTime TIME,
 customerName VARCHAR(40),
 creditCardNo CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 customerRanking ENUM('platinum','gold','occasional','one-off'),
 CONSTRAINT fk_Routes FOREIGN KEY (routeNo) REFERENCES Stop(routeNo),
 CONSTRAINT fk_Stops FOREIGN KEY (stopNo) REFERENCES Stop(stopNo),   
 CONSTRAINT fk_Dates FOREIGN KEY (deliveryDateExpected) REFERENCES Workday(theDate)
);
```

However every time i try to create the OrderDelivery table it gives the error that the foreign key is incorrectly formed

```
"SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'harry.OrderDelivery' (errno:150)Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
```

How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a foreign key to a table with a multiple primary key referencing only one field of that primary key.

So your problem lies here:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Routes FOREIGN KEY (routeNo) REFERENCES Stop(routeNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_Stops FOREIGN KEY (stopNo) REFERENCES Stop(stopNo),
```

You should change it to

```
 CONSTRAINT fk_Stops_Routes 
    FOREIGN KEY (routeNo, stopNo) 
    REFERENCES Stop(routeNo, stopNo),
```

Or depending on your requirements you have to change your model to fit your needs.